# Generic Card Odds

Tags: probability, card-games

First time poster and not a mathematician by training, so please explain things to me as in simple terms!

**I'm looking for a generic formula that can be used to calculate the odds of drawing at least one card of a given value in hands of variable sizes from a deck of variable sizes.**

To elaborate:

Suppose I have a standard 52-card deck, and I want to find the odds of drawing at least 1 Ace in a hand of 5 cards.  Is there a generic formula into which I can insert the numbers "52" (size of deck), "5" (size of hand) and "4" (number of Aces), to produce the answer?

*I'm looking for a generic answer because I want to play around with things a bit.  Let's say the deck is now smaller because 2 of the Aces and all the 7s have been removed, and I can only draw 3 cards...I want to be able to quickly and easily substitute in "46", "3" and "2".*

Hope that makes sense!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: It may be simpler to find the probability that the hand does not contain an ace, then subtract that probability from 1 in order to find the probability of having at least one ace.

Comment: The words [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) and [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) are not synonymous.  I suspect you really are interested in calculating the probability.